# c# regex to javascript

Tags: c#, javascript, regex

I have a line of code on the server that I want to move to the client page in javascript.

```
string ThePhone = "1234567890";
string ThisFormat = Regex.Replace(ThePhone, @"(\d{3})(\d{3})(\d{4})", "$1-$2-$3");
```

It's supposed to return `123-456-7890`. How can I change this to javascript?

Thanks.

Comment: @Marcus: tried several trial-and-error changes. Can you help?

Comment: Kobi's answer should work. Here's an example were the given example works: http://jsfiddle.net/BBTfN/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is almost exactly the same in this case:

```
phone = phone.replace(/(\d{3})(\d{3})(\d{4})/, '$1-$2-$3');
```

Notes:

- You need the `/g` flag (`/.../g`) if the string may contain more than one phone (but then we may also want `\b`)
- `\d` in .Net matches all Unicode digits, in JavaScript it only matches `[0-9]`.

Comment: In addition, there are other ways to achieve that - you can insert dashes at the right positions, or you replace `/(\d{3})(\d{3})/` with `'$1-$2-'`.

Comment: It doesn't seem to work; I know it's close but I've struggling with this conversion too. It only contains one phone; it's a string of 10 digits. When I alert the result, I get the same initial string.

Comment: @frenchie - Works for me: http://jsbin.com/esoyat . Did you forget the `phone =` part by any chance?

Comment: Ok, I got it: a bit earlier in the code, I was looping through the phone number and doing a parseInt on each character to see if it was an int. When it got to the 0, it dropped that character so I was actually passing 123456789 instead of the 10 digits. Thanks for your help.